# How to select data from DB based on column data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to create an explore page for my social site. I am basically done but I have a bad bug.

If the unfollowed column is `0` then I don't want to see the posts of the people I am following. If it's `1` then I want to see it. If the row doesn't exist at all then I still want to see it.

So if my name is in the `user_from` column and the number in the unfollowed column is 0, Then I don't want to see that person's post. If the number is `1` or if my name isn't in that specific column in the row, then I want to see the post.

Right now, if my name is in just one row in the `user_from` column and the number is 1 then I don't see any posts at all in my explore page. Any idea what to do ?

```
$user_following_query = $con->prepare('SELECT user_from FROM following WHERE ? in (user_from) AND 
    unfollowed="0"');
$user_following_query->bind_param("s", $userLoggedIn);
$user_following_query->execute();
$user_following_query->bind_result($user_following);    
$user_following_query_result = $user_following_query->get_result();

while ($row = $user_following_query_result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $user_following = $row['user_from'];
}

if($userLoggedIn == $user_following) {

    //echo "";
    die('No explore posts to show.');
    
} else {
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can't bind columns.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner So any ideas on what to do ?

Comment: Create a safelist is all you can do.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Where do they bind columns?

Comment: @Dharman What do you call `WHERE ?` < that?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner It's a value, the sentence just before explains that they compare the value to the column `user_from`. Are you confused by the reversed order of operands?

Comment: Should the `WHERE` clause be:  `WHERE user_from IN (?) AND ...`?

Comment: @PaulT. Like this ? `'SELECT user_from FROM following WHERE user_from IN (?) '`

Comment: ...and the rest of the query, I just stopped at the `AND`: `'SELECT user_from FROM following WHERE user_from IN (?) AND unfollowed="0"'`

Comment: @PaulT. That didn't work either

Comment: Is a logged-in user a single name, as shown in the table, or is there more to the login, such as an email suffix?  (i.e. user@domain.com)

Comment: There's an email and a name column

Comment: Can your try running `SELECT user_from FROM following WHERE user_from IN ('Brandon') AND unfollowed="0"` in phpMyAdmin, does it show any result?

Comment: @PaulT. I got one result

Comment: That's what I would have expected. Hmmm, something amiss somewhere...

Comment: @PaulT. I'll keep trying

Comment: Echo the `$userLoggedIn` somewhere to ensure the value is as expected. (That it contains `Brandon`, and not something else)

Comment: Yeah it's correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219468/discussion-between-paul-t-and-brandon-t).

Comment: I don't get it. Forget the php stuff for now, and just focus on the sql. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query